# cannot load date picker in fancybox

Tags: jquery, datepicker, fancybox, lightbox

I am using [this picker with jquery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/):

When I call the picker inside a fancybox lightbox using the script below, it does not activate. No java error or anything, just doesnt respond. It works fine if fancybox is not called. Using jquery 1.7.2

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">           
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker1").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "1900:2013"
  });                                               

  $( "#datepicker2").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "1900:2013"
  });                                               

  $( "#datepicker3").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "1900:2013"
  });                                               

});
</script>
```

Comment: how do you call inside fancybox? ...maybe you need to initialize the date picker using the `afterShow` callback (fancybox v2.1.4+)

Comment: I was calling fancybox in a manner that wasn't correct.
I WAS calling it like this: $.fancybox($("##new_overlay").html(),{});
when I should have been doing this: $(".mypopupoverlay").fancybox().trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

I was calling fancybox incorrectly.